# How to make the x axis of a graph sequential dates when dates in the dataframe are not sequential?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

let's say I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Date': '3/4/2021', 'count': 2}, {'Date': '3/6/2021', 'count': 3}, {'Date': '3/12/2021', 'count': 5}], columns = ['Date', 'count'])
```

If I graph simply

```
df.plot(x = 'Date, y='count')
```

Then the dates on the x axis will be woefully un-sequential and I won't have a useable time horizon on the x axis. How can I make the x axis just a sequential list of dates and then have the plot populated based on whether the value of df['Date'] matches the date on the x axis?

Comment: You will probably have to format the date as time and not as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the date as date time instead of string.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')
df.plot(x='Date', y='count')
```

Depending on your localization you will have to change the format to ‘%m/%d/%Y’

[image]

Comment: note that `format` generally isn't needed. pandas has pretty good auto-detection.